# How to determine the request URI in a JAX-RS client's MessageBodyReader?

Tags: client, jax-rs, jsr311

I am implementing a custom `MessageBodyReader` that needs to resolve URIs against the request URI during processing. If the `MessageBodyReader` is used in a JAX-RS *server* implementation, which eg. processes incoming POST requests, I can obtain the request URI from a `UriInfo` object that is injected at runtime using `@Context` (as described eg. at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314076):

```
public class MyProvider implements MessageBodyReader {

  @javax.ws.rs.core.Context
  javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo uriInfo;

  @Override
  public Iterable<URI> readFrom(Class<Iterable<URI>> clazz, Type genericType,
      Annotation annotations[], MediaType mediaType,
      MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    URI requestURI = uriinfo.getAbsolutePath(); // NPE if called in a client

    // Parsing entityStream resolving relative URIs using requestURI

  }
}
```

If the `MessageBodyReader` is called in a JAX-RS *client* implementation during the reading of an `Response`'s entity, the injection does not happen, hence I get a `NullPointerException` (see above for the line) when I write a client using JAX-RS like:

```
Iterable<URI> it = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://example.org/").request().get()
    .readEntity(new GenericType<Iterable<URI>>(){});
```

With the aim of resolving URIs, my question is:

**How do I find out the request URI in `readFrom(...)` in the case that the `MessageBodyReader` is called in a JAX-RS *client* implementation?**

*My current workaround:* Having read [Chapter 10.4 "Filter and interceptor execution order"](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9614) of the Jersey documentation, I found that in step 16, the `ClientResponseFilter`, I have access to both the request URI and the response headers. Hence I wrote a `ClientResponseFilter` that puts the request URI in a custom response header. Then, I can retrieve that custom header from the 5th parameter of `readFrom(...)`.

Comment: Why can't you just do a null check on the UriInfo?

Comment: Then I would know that I don't have UriInfo, but where do I get the URI from?

Comment: OiC. I overlooked that part of the question. You're workaround seems like your best bet. Probably something I would have thought of if faced with the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and I think methods in `MessageBody(Reader|Writer)` are badly designed. They should have been designed like the interceptors and filters which only have some `*Context`s parameters. An hypothetic `MessageBodyReaderContext` could have contained all parameters + properties (like other contexts) that could have been filled by some `ClientRequestFilter` which has access to the URI.